# Load a Level as child of Current level in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to load next screen with previous screen also visible to user. Something like that

[image]

as previous screen is covered with light white background and above it content of my next screen will appear. Can someone please guide me regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Application.LoadLevelAdditive:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditive.html

Comment: It's mixing both levels, not adding a layer on previous level. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've updated question. Can you please help me now @LVBen